# 'Unable to locate package swig-wx' Error When Trying to Install swig-wx

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm trying to build rxtools and turtlesim package (following ROS tutorials ['8. Using rxconsole and roslaunch'](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRxconsoleRoslaunch)), but when I try the command

> mehrdad@ubuntu:~$ rosdep install rxtools turtlesim </samp></p></blockquote>
> I get: 
> <blockquote><p><samp>executing command [sudo apt-get install swig-wx]
> <br>[sudo] password for mehrdad: 
> <br>Reading package lists... Done
> <br>Building dependency tree       
> <br>Reading state information... Done
> <br>E: Unable to locate package swig-wx
> <br>ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
> <br>  apt: command [sudo apt-get install swig-wx] failed </samp></p></blockquote>
> Then, when I try the above command (<samp>sudo apt-get install swig-wx</samp>), I get this error: 
> <blockquote><p><samp>mehrdad@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install swig-wx
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree       
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package swig-wx

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48150/%27unable-to-locate-package-swig-wx%27-error-when-trying-to-install-swig-wx/) by [Merdad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3506/merdad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a rosdistro commit related to swig-wx:
[Added swig-wx rules to base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/ecaed7160e6d53a473220025209758b9bfe69ce4)

But I can't find the package named 'swig-wx' in packages.ubuntu.com.

So I removed the following lines from ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/0a12...(please check that this is a cache of https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml)

```
swig-wx:
  debian: swig-wx
  ubuntu: {lucid: swig-wx, oneiric: swig-wx, precise: swig-wx, quantal: swig-wx}
```

Then rosdep seems to work well.

---

Originally posted by [tnakaoka](https://answers.ros.org/users/3580/tnakaoka/) with karma: 36 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem is relevant to ubuntu instead of ROS.

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

first. If this doesn't work, you can reference

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1629083

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1